# How can I disable the saving bookmark function for specific page just via the html code?

Tags: javascript, html, bookmarks

the requeirment is that I want to avoid the specific web page to save to bookmark, 
and is there someway to acheive this funcion just use some code, maybe add  or js code . thanks

Comment: You can't, it's specific functionality to the browser.

Comment: Can't really, I can just copy and paste the url to a notepad, and that could be my bookmark. Why are you trying to prevent bookmark? What are you trying to accomplish? The community may be able to provide you with direction if you give us more information.

Comment: I am handling a goverment web CMS project via Drupal, and in some specific web pages, the admin user just want some normal user to read the content, but dont want to allow them to save those web page to their web browser bookmark. I can disabled the web page cache via add some <meta> function, but the bookmark function seems no way..thx

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no, the user can always bookmark a page as this is browser function, but you can use sessions. Then make sure that any request for a page
must have an active session id or it returns an error or redirects to the home page. The user can bookmark the page but the bookmarks will then only work for a short time (until the session expires). This also has the added benefit of
making the site impossible to index by search engines.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you're going to get is if you open another window using JavaScript as you can control whether the menubar and toolbar are displayed.

```
window.open(
"https://www.google.com/",
"Google",
"resizable,scrollbars,status");
```

However, this is likely going to be blocked by their popup blocker.